# Counting the occurrence of an element in an array assembly MASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, masm

Hi so I'm having lots of trouble with my display count on this assembly project. This is what I have to do: Generate an array counts which holds the number of times each value in the range [LO, HI] ([15, 50] for default constant values) is seen in randArray (a random array), even if the number of times a value is seen is zero.
For example with LO=15, counts[0] should equal the number of instances of the value `15` in array. counts[14] should equal the number of instances of the value `29` in randArray. Note that some value may appear zero times and should be reported as zero instances.

Any help is appreciated, thank you

This is what I have:

```
;constants:
HI = 50
LO = 15
ARRAYSIZE = 20
LINE_LIMIT = 5

....
countList PROC

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov edx, 1
    mov ecx, ARRAYSIZE
    mov edi, [ebp+12]
    mov ebx, [edi]

    countLoop:
    sub ebx, LO
    mov esi, [ebp+8]
    add esi, ebx
    add [esi], edx
    mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteDec
    add edi, 4
    mov ebx, [edi]
    loop countLoop

    pop ebp
    ret 8
countList ENDP


displayCounts PROC

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov esi, [ebp+12]
    mov ecx, 20
    mov edx, [ebp+8]
    call CrLf
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    mov ebx, 0 ;to keep track of the elements per line

    displayElement:
    mov eax, [esi]
    call WriteDec
    mov edx, OFFSET twoSpace
    call WriteString
    inc ebx

    ;To check if the maximum limit of integers per line is reached
    cmp ebx, LINE_LIMIT
    jl skipNextLine
    call CrLf
    mov ebx, 0 ;the counter is refreshed

    skipNextLine:
    add esi, 4 ;move to next element of the array
    loop displayElement

    pop ebp
    ret 8

displayCounts ENDP

....
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @ErikEidt with the codes above I wasn’t able to get any values on the list so i want some helps on if my current codes is right or wrong and where should i go next?

Comment: Have you considered debugging it?  If so, where is it first going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misinterpreted the task description.

The **source** data that you have to process comes from the *randArray* array that contains *ARRAYSIZE* (20) elements. Their values are random, so there's no evidence that all of these values would be in the range [15,50]. Therefore just using `sub ebx, LO` is not enough! You need to check whether the source element belongs to the given numerical range. Only if it does, will it be safe to calculate the correct offset in the **destination** array. Furthermore, the offset in the destination array needs scaling by 4 since you're dealing with dwords here.
The destination array will have 36 elements (HI - LO + 1), and so having an hardcoded `mov ecx, 20` in the *displayCounts* procedure is wrong.

> ```
> mov esi, [ebp+8]
> add esi, ebx
> add [esi], edx
> ```

The x86 instruction set has very powerful addressing modes. You can add the 2 address components together here and avoid having to reload the base address all the time. Next, you don't need to use an extra register set to 1 only for the purpose of adding it to the count. Use the `inc` instruction but let MASM know the size of the operation by mentioning `dword ptr`.

> ```
> mov eax, [esi]
> call WriteDec
> ```

It is confusing to display these temporary values while still building the result.

> ```
> add esi, 4
> mov ebx, [esi]
> loop countLoop
> ```

Here you should not be reading a further element from the array. If the count is exhausted, you could trigger a segmentation fault by reading from memory that is not available.

---

Next is my version of the counting loop. I'm assuming that you will have cleared the memory for the destination array beforehand (all 36 dwords set to 0):

```
countList PROC
    mov  edi, [esp + 4]            ; Destination array
    mov  esi, [esp + 8]            ; Source array
    mov  ecx, ARRAYSIZE            ; Number of elements in source
  .More:
    mov  eax, [esi]                ; An element from randArray
    add  esi, 4
    sub  eax, LO
    jb   .Skip                     ; Value is outside [LO,HI]
    cmp  eax, (HI - LO)
    ja   .Skip                     ; Value is outside [LO,HI]
    inc  dword ptr [edi + eax * 4] ; EAX=[0,35]
  .Skip:
    dec  ecx
    jnz  .More
    ret  8
countList ENDP
```

---

And finally: **You need to include some comments in your program. At the very least should you document the input parameters for your procedures**. eg. I still haven't decided what is at `[ebp+8]` and `[ebp+12]` in your *displayCounts* procedure...

Comment: The project is actually asking for a size 20 random array of range 15 to 50. And I have to count the occurrence of each element that appear in that random array. I have thought of doing the count on the sorted array [15,15,15,45,49...], thus the count array would be [3,1,1..]. Im having trouble implementing this though, any ideas? Thank you @Sep Roland

Comment: '''countList PROC
   ...
    mov     ESI, [EBP + 8]            ; randArray
    mov     ECX, ARRAYSIZE          ; loop counter 
    
    mov     Edi, [EBP + 16]            ;  (countArray)
    
 mov ebx, lo

    _FirstLoop:
        ; grab first digit of sorted array
        mov     EAX, [ESI]

        ; compare current value to next value
  ;mov ebx, lo
        cmp     EAX,LO
        je      _NextDigit
        jne     _AddCountArray'''